# Two AJAX GET request calls not working on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a page `index.php` and I load all other pages into a div contained within this page.

- `results.php` runs the search and displays data.
- `profile_v.php` reads a specific text file parses the data and displays it.

Both of these pages require a GET request to feed data into them and both of them have their own AJAX calls to make do the relative action.

All AJAX call functions are in `index.php`. When I put the `profile_v.php` AJAX call in `index.php`, the `result.php` AJAX call doesn't work anymore.

**`profile_v.php` AJAX call and parser:**

```
function parser2(code) {
    var cpdata = code.split('\n');
    var i = 0;
    var res;
    var len = cpdata.length;
    while (i < len) {
        res = cpdata[i].split(',');
        //alert(res[0]+" -> "+res[1]);
        document.getElementById(res[0]).innerHTML = res[1];
        i++;
    }
}

function prof_load() {
    //alert('hi');
    var str = '<?php echo $_GET['
    user '];?>';
    //alert(str);
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            //document.getElementById('junk').innerHTML = this.responseText;
            parser2(this.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "action_page.php", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send("profld1=" + str);
}
```

**`results.php` AJAX call:**

```
function search() {
    var query = document.getElementById('search').value;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("frame").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "result.php?query=" + query, true);
    xhttp.send();
}

function prof_click(str) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("frame").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "profile_v.php?user=" + str, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

**Expected Flow:**

- browsing-user enters a text in search field and `search()` executes.
- search displays usernames relative to the searched keyword.
- browsing-user clicks on the username(div) -> `prof_click()` executes.
- `prof-click()` sends a GET request to `profile_v.php` where `prof_load()` is run on body onload.

**Problem:**

- When I load these pages separately, and not via AJAX calls, it works.
- When I put all the AJAX calls into `index.php`, the search button itself stops working ... (`search()` does not execute)
- The GET request from `prof_click()` goes to `profile_V.php` also works when the other two functions are not added to `index.php`.
- All of the JS functions are in `index.php`, which has the div to load all the pages. The javascript calls are in the respective pages.
- The problem I'm facing is when the search keyword is entered. The GET request pulls all matching entries in the DB. Matching usernames are shown in a different div. When any are clicked, the prof_click(str) is called. When I echo `$_GET` in `profile_v.php` it shows the passed string which is the profile of the searched keyword (searched user). But when calling `prof_load()`, which is called in body onload, inside the div of index.php no JS functions are executing.
- I tried putting an `alert("string")` inside `prof_load()` and nothing else, and tried running the code again... this time the search worked. However when `profile_v.php` loaded, the alert box did not show.

I have a feeling the GET requests are getting mismatched somewhere. Could someone please tell me what I'm missing here. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: can you check if `prof_load` and `prof_click` functions get called correctly?

Comment: How are you loading your two pages inside index.php? _When I put the profile_v.php_ is just not self-explanatory at all.

Comment: - all the javascript functions are in index.php, which has the div to load all the pages. 

- the javascript calls are in the respective pages.

Comment: - the javascript calls are in the respective pages.

- the problem i am facing is,
-> when the search keyword is entered. GET req pulls all matching entries in the DB.
-> matching usernames are shown in a different div, which when clicked, calls the prof_click(str).
-> when i echo $_GET in the profile_v.php.

--> but when i try to call prof_load, which is called in body onload. inside the div of index.php no js functions are executing.

Comment: so now when all the functions are put together in index.php
search functionality itself stops working

Comment: *when i echo $_GET in the profile_v.php - it show the passed string which is profile of the searched keyword(searched user).

Comment: one thing i tried was, i just put an alert("string") inside prof_load and nothing else ... and tried running the code again this time search worked. but when profile_v.php loaded alert box did not show .

Comment: And thanks in advance @Ben and

Comment: @SaschaM78 ... i have a feeling this something really basic thats getting messed up

Comment: Sorry, got it wrong. Where do you trigger the `search` call in your index.php? And what you wrote in several comments should be added as detailed text in your question, btw. Just use the edit link below the question to add up on it.

Comment: search is triggered from index.php .... and definition is also in index.php.
Would the Request get mixed up over because search is in index.php. ?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to call a page via AJAX ... which had another AJAX call in it.

- index.php calls profile_v.php for the layout of the page.
- profile_v.php calls action_page.php for the data to be fed to profile_v.php.

The call sequence was not correct. I just had to re arrange a few code and put the calls in the right place.

Thanks for the support everyone... Cheers!!